# Strict separation of choice and structure

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, comprehension

I am having difficulty in comprehending the below passage

> Some social scientists, particularly those who are committed to individualism, like the **strict separation of choice and structure** found in game theory because it gives an active edge to choice. Individuals qua individuals are plainly doing something on this account, although how much will depend on what can be said about what is likely to happen in such interactions. **Game theory promises to tell a great deal on this.** By comparison other traditions of political philosophy work with models of human agents who seem more passive and whose contribution merges seamlessly with that of other social factors. Nevertheless the strict separation raises a difficulty regarding the origin of structures.

What is meant by structures here? What does game theory promise to tell us?

Answer (score 1):

In the US, there was recently a recall referendum for Democratic Governor Newsom. The referendum had a certain structure, which was basically:

1. Recall Newsom, Yes or No?
2. If Yes, who from the following list will you vote for?

The *structure* of the referendum made the *choices* problematic for both parties. If the majority of voters had chosen to recall (part 1) then a split vote for part 2 might have gone to an opposition (Republican) candidate.

The author contends that *Game Theory* has much to say about the way individual choices (e.g., whether to recall or not) are affected by the structure of the game (e.g., the way the referendum is laid out and whom to vote for.)